# CodeSanBox Example react-to-print in PC working but laptop not show data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, .net, typescript, react-to-print

I'm following the example codesanbox with react-to-print :https://codesandbox.io/s/kmmw7l39y7?file=/index.js
The PC working Okay but the laptop not work
I don't now why my laptop is not working
Please help me check it
thanks very much
My PC and Driver
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55z1M.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55AoD.png)
My laptop :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUvUU.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWGBq.png)

I just also excute with difference devices
but some of them also don't show data

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What browser  are you using?